# Android move view below another programatically

Tags: android

I have three views that are part of a list view cell.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/postArea"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/date"
        android:id="@+id/shareView">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/shareView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/commentsView">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In some cells "shareView" is set to               `shareView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

When this is the case I need to change `commentsView` so that it is below `postArea` instead.

Its there a way to do this within my getView method.

Comment: I think Linearlayout is the main layout can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set your `shareView's` `visibility` to `View.GONE`, you should change the `layout_below` rule for your `commentsView`. Like this:

```
RelativeLayout commentsView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.commentsView);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)commentsView.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.postArea);
commentsView.requestLayout();
```